# React MODULE_NOT_FOUND error even if it should be correct

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-scripts

recently I've been working with react. I had 4 days free and took a rest. Soon as I started again and tried to **npm start** it displayed error in terminal. Before that I cleared my desktop because it had a lot of folders and I moved that project in other folder. I thought that that might somehow cause the error and I've just tried with new **npx create-react-app my-app**. However this didn't fix error. It displays it on every single react project I have. I've been googling for 2 hours and tried everything although it didn't work. Can somebody please help.

```
Error:
The system cannot find the path specified. 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nijaz\Desktop\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what was problem for me. Actually my folder structure was going like this:
Web Dev & Programming => Udemy ReacJS => -First React Big Project => senbonzakura-food

And this "&" in the "Web Dev & Progamming" was making the probelm.

Comment: Right suggestion. Should not create folders with & operator. After removing it my react app starts working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just Delete the `node_modules` directory, Delete the `package-lock.json` file and `Run npm install`, Run `npm start`.

try this:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Also: You Just need to make Sure that right address path for `app.js` (it should be `app.js, main.js, start.js, server.js`, or whatever you picked up) in out Package.json file.
{"npm": .js}
good luck

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work. I found out what error was. I will post it down. Thank you for your will to help.